# Auto hot key input based on pressed key

Tags: autohotkey

I want to make a script that sends input based answer,

For example, The last input is

```
1:Option1 | 2:option2 | 3:Option3 | 0:Cancel
```

How I can make that If I press on 1 it will send a different imput, and if I press 2 it will send other?
Option 0 will do

```
return
}
```

1:Option1 | 2:option2 | 3:Option3 | 0:Cancel

*Pressing 1*
Sendinput of option 1

Comment: You seem to have already asked [the exact same question](https://superuser.com/questions/706883/how-to-set-input-based-answer). There, people have asked you to clarify your intent, and you didn't react. What's your plan here? Copy-pasting the question over and over again until a miracle happens? Or wouldn't it perhaps be smarter to actually cater to the questions that people ask you?

Answer (score 0):

```
Space::
   TrayTip,, % "begin"
   Loop
   {
      Input, notUsedVar, % "IV", % "{vk31}{vk32}{vk33}{vk34}{vk35}{vk36}{vk37}{vk38}{vk39}{vk30}"
      SendInput, % "{BS}{Raw}"((rRER:=RegExReplace(ErrorLevel, "\w+:"))=0 ? "Cancel":"Option"rRER)
      IfNotEqual, rRER, 0, MsgBox, 262180, % " ", % "Continue?"
      IfNotEqual, rRER, 0, IfMsgBox, No, Break
   }
   Until, rRER=0
   TrayTip,, % "complete"
   Return
```